# C# issue with connection after turning on the computer

Tags: c#, connection, odbc, sqlanywhere

I wanted to connect my application written in C # with the SQL Anywhere 17 database. I was able to use the OdbcConnection class by referring directly to the database driver.

my example:

```
private void butODBC3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DBase = "FTG_001";
        string Host = "192.168.13.4";

        if (testODBC(DBase, Host) == true)
        {
            labODBC.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        }
        else
        {
            labODBC.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private bool testODBC(string DBase, string host)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Driver={SQL Anywhere 17};DatabaseName=" + DBase + ";EngineName=monwin;uid=monodbc;pwd=monodbc;LINKS=tcpip(ClientPort=5050-5060;HOST=" + host + ";PORT=2020;DoBroadcast=NONE)";
        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("select getDate()", connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When you click on the button, the label changes color to green if there is a connection or to red if there is a problem.

Everything works but under one condition ... After turning on the computer, I need to click the Test Connections in the ODBC Data Source Administrator to make my program work correctly. Otherwise, it will not connect to the database.

How can I force the same connection test in ODBC Data Source Administrator ?? Equally effective ...

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The code you posted should work.  I would add a break point in the code to make sure it is actually reaching the code.  The other possibility is the connection string in the ODBC Data Source Administrator is different from the code posted.

Comment: `After turning on the computer, I need to click the Test Connections in the ODBC Data Source Administrator to make my program work correctly. ` If you _don't_ do that, what is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Small change...
The problem with connecting to the database is every time when I lose my connection to the network and connect again.  Here's the `Exception: Exception caught: 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' in System.Data.dll ("ERROR [08001] [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server not found"). 
Exception caught: 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' in System.Data.dll ("ERROR [08001] [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server not found") `